# Ruby modules that use some common method:where to put this method?

Tags: ruby

Given some Uploader Class, I have three modules included in it.

They have each their own distinctive uses and that's why I divided them into three modules. But, as it turns out, there is one method that all three modules need.

So, it is so far obvious to me that there must be a better way than defining this method in each of these three modules. Should I make a fourth module and put this method in it, and have these original three modules include this fourth module? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You could write a generic uploader class with the common methods and then make subclasses with the specific functionality.  If they need to be modules, then a 4th module is probably the most DRY way to perform what you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you should have a fourth module. But it sounds like you might actually need a class hierarchy rather than independent, flat modules. Apply the 'is a' test - can you say *an UploaderA instance **is an** Uploader*? If so, you should have

```
class Uploader
  include FourthModule  # with shared functionality for all uploaders
  # or just go ahead and put the shared functionality right in the Uploader class here.
end

class UploaderA < Uploader
end
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting classes.  That seems like the most appropriate solution for this scenario.

Comment: @THANKS both Peter & Glazier; from what you suggested onward, do then I include those three modules in UploaderA class? And because these modules are included in a subclass UploaderA of class Uploader which has that important, shared method, these modules will "get to ues" this method, too?